# What is IN in the Inteface declaration interface IRepository<T, in TKey>

Tags: .net, interface

Given the very general nature of the word IN. Google / Bing did not give any suitable results. Any elaboration is welcome.

Comment: It's a [generic modifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469484.aspx). If nobody else answers before me I'll post a proper answer.

Comment: Searching for "C# keyword in": the second answer was the correct one (and the first would have led me to it also)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from Wai Ha Lee :  It's a generic modifier. If nobody else answers before me I'll post a proper answer.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469484.aspx